# AngularJS SVG won't load in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I'm was doing some tests in Angular with SVG, and i came with interesting problem which shows up only in Chrome.

If i try this:

```
<object height="30" width="30" type="image/svg+xml" data="test/svg/{{icon}}.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

It will parse it as plain HTML, but only in Chrome.

What is workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solution.
From [AngularJS Developer Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive),

We would expect Angular to be able to bind to this, but when we check the console we see something like Error: Invalid value for attribute cx="{{cx}}". Because of the SVG DOM API's restrictions, you cannot simply write cx="{{cx}}".
With ng-attr-cx you can work around this problem.

If an attribute with a binding is prefixed with the ngAttr prefix (denormalized as ng-attr-) then during the binding will be applied to the corresponding unprefixed attribute. This allows you to bind to attributes that would otherwise be eagerly processed by browsers (e.g. an SVG element's circle[cx] attributes).

Simple as that.